# Pydev can not run the .py file which run well in Terminal

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm start using Pydev in Eclipse.
My phtyon version is 3.4.3
This is my Code that I want to run

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import codecs
fp = codecs.open("/Users/Chois/Desktop/textfile", 'rb', 'utf-8') 


msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
fp.close()

me = "abcd@gmail.com"
you = "efgh@naver.com"
msg['Subject'] = "hi.."
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',465)
s.login(me, "password")
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

It runs well in Terminal by "python test.py".
However, when I tried to run it in Pydev, There are some errors something like belows

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Chois/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 2235, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Users/Chois/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.9.2.201502050007/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1661, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/Chois/Documents/workspace/Test/src/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 226, in set_payload
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 262, in set_charset
    self._payload = self._payload.encode(charset.output_charset)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I don't know why this happen.
And below is the setting that I used when making python project file in Pydev

[image]

I would be really thankful if you gonna give advices or somethings. Thanks.

Comment: You say your python version is 3.4, but `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/` would indicate otherwise (or a misconfiguration).

Comment: Then what shoul i do? I think that elipse only support python 2.7...

Comment: What does `fp = codecs.open("/Users/Chois/Desktop/textfile", 'rb') `


`msg = MIMEText(fp.read())` do?

Comment: Can you change the interpreter? from python to python3.4 or something like this?